# Binary tree algorithm for 2D bin packing

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory-management

I have re-implemented in **C++** an algorithm already in JavaScript available [here](https://codeincomplete.com/posts/bin-packing/) and [there](https://github.com/jakesgordon/bin-packing).

C++ code works fine, but I have memory management concerns:

1. I allocate memory with such statement as `m_root = new Block(...)` dangerously
2. When freeing memory with `if (m_fit) { delete  m_fit; m_fit = nullptr; }`, exceptions are thrown

I feel like my C++ code is leaking memory, I wonder if something is noticeably wrong:

### Calling the algorithm

```cpp
void createBlocks(std::vector<Block> &blocks)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        float w = i * 1.1; // semi-random
        float h = i * 0.9; // semi-random
        float x = i - 10;  // semi-random
        float y = i + 5;   // semi-random
        Block block = Block(w, h, x, y);
        blocks.push_back(block);
    }
}

void sortDescendingInSize(std::vector<Block> &blocks)
{
    std::sort(blocks.begin(), blocks.end(), [](const Block& first, const Block &second) {
        float firstMaxSide  = std::max( first.m_h,  first.m_w);
        float secondMaxSide = std::max(second.m_h, second.m_w);
        // returns ​true if the first argument is ordered before the second
        // order descending
        return firstMaxSide > secondMaxSide;
    });
}

void main()
{
    std::vector<Block> blocks = std::vector<Block>();

    createBlocks(blocks);

    if (blocks.empty())
        return;

    sortDescendingInSize(blocks);

    GrowingPacker growingPacker = GrowingPacker();
    growingPacker.fit(blocks);

    for (const Block &block : blocks) {
        if (block.m_fit && block.m_item) {
            std::cout <<
                      << "w:" << block.m_w << "h:" << block.m_h
                      << "fit->w:" << block.m_fit->m_w << "fit->h:" << block.m_fit->m_h
                      << "fit->x:" << block.m_fit->m_x << "fit->y:" << block.m_fit->m_y;
        }
    }
}
```

### Algorithm class definition

```cpp
#ifndef GROWINGPACKER_H
#define GROWINGPACKER_H

#include "vector"
#include "src/pack/block.h"

class GrowingPacker
{
public:
    GrowingPacker();
    void fit(std::vector<Block> &blocks);

private:
    Block *findNode(Block *root, float w, float h);
    Block *splitNode(Block *node, float w, float h);
    Block *growNode(float w, float h);
    Block *growRight(float w, float h);
    Block *growDown(float w, float h);

private:
    Block *m_root;
};

#endif // GROWINGPACKER_H
```

### Algorithm class implementation

```cpp
#include "growingpacker.h"

GrowingPacker::GrowingPacker()
{

}

void GrowingPacker::fit(std::vector<Block> &blocks)
{
    size_t len = blocks.size();
    float w = len > 0 ? blocks[0].m_w : 0;
    float h = len > 0 ? blocks[0].m_h : 0;
    m_root = new Block(w,h, 0, 0);
    for (Block &block : blocks) {
        Block *node = findNode(m_root, block.m_w, block.m_h);
        if (node)
            block.m_fit = splitNode(node, block.m_w, block.m_h);
        else
            block.m_fit = growNode(block.m_w, block.m_h);
    }
    return;
}

Block *GrowingPacker::findNode(Block *root, float w, float h)
{
    if (root->m_used) {
        Block *tmp = findNode(root->m_right, w, h);
        if (tmp)
            return tmp;
        else
            return findNode(root->m_down, w, h);
    } else if ( w <= root->m_w && h <= root->m_h)
        return root;
    else
        return nullptr;
}

Block *GrowingPacker::splitNode(Block *node, float w, float h)
{
    node->m_used = true;
    node->m_down  = new Block(node->m_w,     node->m_h - h, node->m_x,     node->m_y + h);
    node->m_right = new Block(node->m_w - w, h,             node->m_x + w, node->m_y    );
    return node;
}

Block *GrowingPacker::growNode(float w, float h)
{
    bool canGrowDown  = w <= m_root->m_w;
    bool canGrowRight = h <= m_root->m_h;

    // attempt to keep square-ish by growing right when height is much greater than width
    bool shouldGrowRight = canGrowRight && m_root->m_h >= (m_root->m_w + w);
    // attempt to keep square-ish by growing down  when width  is much greater than height
    bool shouldGrowDown  = canGrowDown  && m_root->m_w >= (m_root->m_h + h);

    if (shouldGrowRight)
        return growRight(w, h);
    else if (shouldGrowDown)
        return growDown(w, h);
    else if (canGrowRight)
        return growRight(w, h);
    else if (canGrowDown)
        return growDown(w, h);
    else
        // need to ensure sensible root starting size to avoid this happening
        return nullptr;
}

Block *GrowingPacker::growRight(float w, float h)
{
    m_root = new Block(m_root->m_w + w
                       , m_root->m_h
                       , 0.0f
                       , 0.0f
                       , true
                       , m_root
                       , new Block(w, m_root->m_h, m_root->m_w, 0.0f)
                       );
    Block *node = findNode(m_root, w, h);
    if (node)
        return splitNode(node, w, h);
    else
        return nullptr;
}

Block *GrowingPacker::growDown(float w, float h)
{
    m_root = new Block(m_root->m_w
                       , m_root->m_h + h
                       , 0.0f
                       , 0.0f
                       , true
                       , new Block (m_root->m_w, h, 0.0f, m_root->m_h)
                       , m_root
                       );
    Block *node = findNode(m_root, w, h);
    if (node)
        return splitNode(node, w, h);
    else
        return nullptr;
}
```

### Block/node class definition which is used by algorithm

```cpp
#ifndef BLOCK_H
#define BLOCK_H

class EditorSceneItem;

class Block
{
public:
    Block();
    Block(float w, float h, float x, float y);
    Block(float w, float h, float x, float y,
          bool used,
          Block *down, Block *right);
    // Copy constructor
    Block(const Block &other);
    // Copy assignment operator
    Block & operator= ( const Block& other );
    // Destructor
    ~Block();
    // Move constructor
    Block(Block&& other);
    // Move assignment operator
    Block& operator=(Block &&other);

private:
    void freePossibleAllocatedMemory();
    void releaseResourcesWithoutFreeingMemory();
    void swapInto(Block& destination) const noexcept;

public:
    float m_w;
    float m_h;
    float m_x;
    float m_y;
    bool m_used;
    Block *m_down = nullptr;
    Block *m_right = nullptr;
    Block *m_fit = nullptr;
};

#endif // BLOCK_H
```

### Block/node class implementation

```cpp
#include "block.h"

Block::Block()
    :
      m_w(0.0f), m_h(0.0f)
    , m_x(0.0f), m_y(0.0f)
    , m_used(false)
    , m_down(nullptr)
    , m_right(nullptr)
    , m_fit(nullptr)
{

}

Block::Block(float w, float h, float x, float y)
    :
      m_w(w), m_h(h)
    , m_x(x), m_y(y)
    , m_used(false)
    , m_down(nullptr)
    , m_right(nullptr)
    , m_fit(nullptr)
{

}

Block::Block(float w, float h, float x, float y,
             bool used,
             Block *down, Block *right)
    :
      m_w(w), m_h(h)
    , m_x(x), m_y(y)
    , m_used(used)
    , m_down(down)
    , m_right(right)
    , m_fit(nullptr)
{

}

Block::Block(const Block &other)
    :
      m_w(other.m_w), m_h(other.m_h)
    , m_x(other.m_x), m_y(other.m_y)
    , m_used(other.m_used)
    , m_down(other.m_down)
    , m_right(other.m_right)
    , m_fit(other.m_fit)
{}

Block & Block::operator= ( const Block& other )
{
    // Self assignment
    if (&other == this)
        return *this;

    this->freePossibleAllocatedMemory();
    other.swapInto(*this);
    return *this;
}

Block::~Block()
{
    freePossibleAllocatedMemory();
}

Block::Block(Block&& other)
    : Block() // delegate to the default constructor
{
    other.swapInto(*this);
    other.releaseResourcesWithoutFreeingMemory();
}

Block& Block::operator=(Block &&other)
{
    // Self assignment
    if (this == &other)
        return *this;

    this->freePossibleAllocatedMemory();

    other.swapInto(*this);
    other.releaseResourcesWithoutFreeingMemory();
    return *this;
}

void Block::freePossibleAllocatedMemory()
{

    // ** STRANGE: an exception is thrown at following lines when freeing memory
    // Exception is avoided by commenting out lines
    // Exception is possibly due to bad memory management

    if (m_down) {
        delete m_down;
        m_down = nullptr;
    }
    if (m_right) {
        delete m_right;
        m_right = nullptr;
    }
    if (m_fit) {
        delete  m_fit;
        m_fit = nullptr;
    }

}

void Block::releaseResourcesWithoutFreeingMemory()
{
    // Release source
    m_w = 0.0f;
    m_h = 0.0f;
    m_x = 0.0f;
    m_y = 0.0f;
    m_used = false;
    m_down = nullptr;
    m_right = nullptr;
    m_fit = nullptr;
}

void Block::swapInto(Block& destination) const noexcept
{
    destination.m_w = m_w; // Don't check equality of float
    destination.m_h = m_h;
    destination.m_x = m_x;
    destination.m_y = m_y;
    if (destination.m_used != m_used)
        destination.m_used = m_used;
    if (destination.m_down != m_down)
        destination.m_down = m_down;
    if (destination.m_right != m_right)
        destination.m_right = m_right;
    if (destination.m_fit != m_fit)
        destination.m_fit = m_fit;
}
```

Thanks for your review =)

Comment: Instead of managing memory allocation / deallocation manually you could use [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) with the correct semantics you need.

Comment: _"When freeing memory with if (m_fit) { delete  m_fit; m_fit = nullptr; }, exceptions are thrown"_ Note that your question is _off-topic_ for Code Review. Only working code is ready for review.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks, I edited it out.

Comment: Well, I am afraid editing out doesn't make that much better. Does your code throw exceptions or not? If so, it's not working properly.

Comment: Recommended read: [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @πάνταῥεῖ I replaced all instances of `Block *` pointer in the code with `std::shared_ptr<Block>` and I feel much better regarding memory management.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks. Also the exception is resolved after implementing `std::shared_ptr<>` =)

Comment: would you please explain your answer further, to make this more of a review?

Comment: @Malachi Thanks, I'm going to explain further.